# How to add data after comparison in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two tables (mark and enroll). Mark table contains two students (ally, hassan) while Enroll table contains four students (ally, hassan, zuwena, saada).

I need to compare these two tables, then after comparison to add missing students from enroll table into mark table without duplication.

But I'm using codeigniter.

I tried this but I got errors'

```
$data['exam_id']    = $this->input->post('exam_id');
    $data['class_id']   = $this->input->post('class_id');
    $data['section_id'] = $this->input->post('section_id');
    $data['subject_id'] = $this->input->post('subject_id');
    $data['year']       = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type'=>'running_year'))->row()->description;
    $query = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                'exam_id' => $data['exam_id'],
                'class_id' => $data['class_id'],
                'section_id' => $data['section_id'],
                'subject_id' => $data['subject_id'],
                'year' => $data['year']
                ))->result_array();



                $query1 = $this->db->get_where('enroll', array(

                'class_id' => $data['class_id'],
                'section_id' => $data['section_id'],
                'year' => $data['year']))->result_array();

                 $query3 = count($query1);
                $query4 = count($query);
                if ($query3 != $query4){
                $students = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array(
                'class_id' => $data['class_id'] , 'section_id' => $data['section_id'] , 'year' => $data['year']))->result_array();
                foreach($students as $row) 
                {

                $data['student_id'] = $row['student_id'];
                $this->db->not_like('mark' , $data);
                $query5 = $this->db->from('mark');                                              
                $this->db->insert('mark' , $query5);

                }
```

Comment: No idea what you are trying to accomplish, you will have to be *alot* more specific and narrow down the problem a bit yourself. e.g. `                $query5 = $this->db->where_not_in('mark', $data);
                $this->db->insert('mark', $query5);` makes no sense

Comment: The question is already updated. @Alex

Comment: I would say it is even worse now as you removed any relevant code that you might have had before and instead expect us to somehow guess at everything including your db structure.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your previous codes, if you want to add the missing `mark` data from `enroll` data, you could change your `foreach` block to :

```
        if ($query3 != $query4){
            // first get all the mark student_id data
            $mark_student_id = $this->db->select('student_id')->get('mark')->result_array();
            // then filter enroll data which does not contain mark student_id data
            $new_students = $this->db->where( array(
                'class_id' => $data['class_id'] , 'section_id' => $data['section_id'] , 'year' => $data['year']
            ))->where_not_in('student_id' , array_column($mark_student_id, 'student_id'))->get('enroll')->result_array();
            // then insert filtered enroll data to mark table
            $this->db->insert('mark' , $new_students);
```

you could restore the previous codes on your question

Comment: Thanks @Hasta but it generate error, Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::where_not_in()

Comment: Its failed again, error "you have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual ....".

Comment: I have got this, you must use the "set"  method to update an entry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hasta Dhana, I have done a little changes to your answer according to my needs and to solve this error "you have to use the set method to update an entry" as follows,

```
if ($query3 != $query4){

                        // first get all the mark student_id data
                        $this->db->where(array('exam_id' => $data['exam_id'],'subject_id' => $data['subject_id']));
                        $mark_student_id = $this->db->select('student_id')->get('mark')->result_array();

                        if(count($mark_student_id)>0){
                        // then filter enroll data which does not contain mark student_id data
                        $new_students = $this->db->where( array(
                                'class_id' => $data['class_id'] , 'section_id' => $data['section_id'] , 'year' => $data['year']

                            ))->where_not_in('student_id' , array_column($mark_student_id, 'student_id'))->get('enroll');
                        // then insert filtered enroll data to mark table

                        if($new_students->num_rows()>0){

                            foreach ($new_students->result_array() as $row){

                            $data['student_id'] = $row['student_id'];
                           $this->db->insert('mark' , $data);

                            }

                        }
                    }else {
                    $data1['exam_id']    = $this->input->post('exam_id');
                    $data1['class_id']   = $this->input->post('class_id');
                    $data1['section_id'] = $this->input->post('section_id');
                    $data1['subject_id'] = $this->input->post('subject_id');
                    $data1['year']       = $this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type'=>'running_year'))->row()->description;
                    $students = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array(
                        'class_id' => $data1['class_id'] , 'section_id' => $data1['section_id'] , 'year' => $data1['year']))->result_array();
                    foreach($students as $row) 
                    {
                        $data1['student_id'] = $row['student_id'];
                        $this->db->insert('mark' , $data1);
                    }

                }
            }
```

That is how was done, thanks.